# What do these HTML attributes for the button tag mean?

Tags: html, angular, attributes, angular-material

I've encountered this HTML somewhere:

```
<button class="button--standard" mat-button mat-flat-button [disabled]=true >Disabled State</button>
```

I've never seen attributes of this format (`mat-button mat-flat-button [disabled]=true`) in HTML. What do they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mat-button, mat-flat-button** are specific attributes to Angular Material !

Overview here : [Angular material buttons](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview)

And **disabled** is a native boolean HTML attribute !

Overview here : [disabled attribute HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp)

Answer (score 1):

These attributes are used for **Angular material buttons** for material design styling.

For information visit the  [official link](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview).